# jQuery .fadeIn() overlay (after another browser tab viewing)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a script to show numbers on a background, which are fading in and out. 
(some kind of matrix theme)

everything works fine until I leave a page to see any other browser tab. When I go back to tab with my script, numbers (that are fading in and out) overlay/overlap. As far as I understand setInterval() begins to knock off my function codeGhost() time intervals on a period of time that this tab was inactive.

Are there any ways to synchronize setInterval() and codeGhost() function not to have this issues, if user comes back from other browser tab back to page with my script??

Best regards.

```
var codeElement = 1;
function randomIntNum(){
    codeElement = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
}
function getRandomInt(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    function codeGhost(){ 
     $("#codeGhost").css({
        'top' : getRandomInt(0,400),
        'left': getRandomInt(0,900)
    });
        randomIntNum();
        $('#codeGhost').html(codeElement);
        $('#codeGhost').fadeIn( 2000, function(){ $('#codeGhost').fadeOut( 2000) });
    }
    setInterval(codeGhost, 4000);
})
```

Comment: Is there a fiddle that we can play around with?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/9MFyz/

Comment: I caught it now again, after i minimized browsers window, for a few seconds and opened fiddle again.

Comment: Sometimes the pauses between fadeIn are just getting longer and other time numbers are overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't have to declare your codeGhost() function inside your document ready handler - only your setInterval - so you could move that outside of the function, that's probably good practice.

Your fiddle seems to work ok but possibly you're getting multiple timeouts conflicting. I would change

```
setInterval(codeGhost, 4000);
```

for

```
setTimeout(codeGhost, 4000);
```

and then call the next timeout from within your codeGhost() function each time it runs:

```
function codeGhost(){ 
    $("#codeGhost").css({
        'top' : getRandomInt(0,400),
        'left': getRandomInt(0,900)
    });
    randomIntNum();
    $('#codeGhost').html(codeElement);
    $('#codeGhost').fadeIn(2000, function(){ 
        $('#codeGhost').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            setTimeout(codeGhost, 4000);
        });
    });    
}
```

Comment: no luck. 
I made it run faster and now you definately can see how it's iverlapping.
http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/9MFyz/3/

Comment: Any other ideas, how can .fadeIn() and setTimeout() be synchronized?

Comment: Sorry - hadn't realised the fades were at similar times to your timeout. You can have a callback function on each of those fades, so call your timeout after everything is completed - then nothing should run until it's finished and no overlaps.
`$('#codeGhost').fadeIn(2000, function(){ 
 $('#codeGhost').fadeOut(2000, function () {
  setTimeout(codeGhost, 4000);
 })
})`

Comment: OH! Now it looks so obvious, pure logic )) Thank you. 
Definitely I was looking for a decision in a wrong direction ))